# Should i use cupertino or not

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I Will start to build Flutter App for both android and ios So I don't know when I use Cupertino and if I can just create it for android without any ios widget (Cupertino) will it be okay and then I can convert it into ios or not?

For like I don't have to worry about the ios version just I will build it for android then what I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just build it with material widgets it will look like that. If you care about having it styled after an iOS style then you will have to incorporate both. But you can just create it for android and it will still run on iOS regardless of the styling.